# Is there a raga in Hindustani or Carnatic classical music with this note-set?

Tags: indian-classical

I'm looking to identify the audav-sampuurNa raga that has the following aaroh / avaroh.

**Hindustani notation**:

> SRGPnS', S'ndPmGRS
> *Aaroh / ascent*:    Sha.Daj, shuddh R^iShabh, shuddh ga.ndhaar, pa.ncham, komal nishaad, Sha.Daj
> *Avaroh / descent*:   Sha.Daj, komal nishaad, komal dhaivat, Pancham, shuddh madhyam, shuddh ga.ndhaar, shuddh R^iShabh, Sha.Daj

**Carnatic notation**:

> SR2G3PN2S, SN2D1PM1G3R2S
> *Aaroh / ascent*:   Sa, chatushruti Ri, a.ntara Ga, shuddha ma, kaishikii Ni, Sa
> *Avaroh / descent*:   Sa, kaishikii Ni, shuddha Dha, Pa, shuddha ma, a.ntara Ga, chatushruti Ri, Sa

In the latter it would be a janya of the 26th mela, Charukeshi.

It's not a given that such a raga exists, in the sense of being named in classical theory or circulating in classical performance. I came across this scale because [Manas Mukherjee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manas_Mukherjee) has used it for [a Hindi film song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ta24hpDai-I) in 1979. So I was wondering whether he based the song on any particular raga or whether he just used an ad hoc set of notes.

Note: I'm **not** asking for a straightforward identification of the raga of this song. I mention the song just as background info in case someone is curious why I'd be asking about this particular scale, and wants to hear what it sounds like in the wild. But the question would remain even without the song.

Comment: Regarding the close vote, this is not a request to identify the raga but, rather whether the raga _that is identified in the question_ exists.  (I presume that "exists" in this context means "is to be found in classical theory" or perhaps "has been used in compositions other than the one mentioned in the question.")  Once again, this close reason shows itself to be problematic because, as it is currently worded, it filters out from this music theory site interesting questions concerning music theory.

Comment: I don't have the rep to see close votes, but yeah, to anybody who knows Indian classical music, this is clearly not an "identify the raga of this piece" question. I've described the parameters of the raga in sufficient detail for someone more knowledgeable than me to identify it *if it exists*. Existence being predicated on its being identified in the theory and/or circulating in classical performance.

Comment: Perhaps rewording the question to ask something more like, "does this set of notes fit the parameters of a raga or is it just an arbitrary set of notes?" might help clarify the question. Also, I wonder if asking in both contexts of Hindustani and Carnatic is too broad. Are there more than 72 Carnatic ragas? If not then the answer to whether this fits a Carnatic raga seems simple. The Hindustani raga tradition is more problematic. In that case, it does seem like an identification question.

Comment: Another aspect of this question is that it seems to verify that this is a raga would also be to name the raga, right? An answer that says "yes, this is a raga" wouldn't be satisfying, would it? Would a good answer require a name and reference for the raga? As in "yes, this raga is called *raga name* and it was used in *song*". If that is the type of answer you are looking for, then to me that **is** an identification question.

Comment: @ToddWilcox yes, there are definitely more than 72 ragas in Carnatic music. Mistaking the 72 scales or melakartaas as exhausting the universe of all Carnatic ragas is a categorical error, and a fairly elementary one to make in the context of that music. A similar categorical error underlies your second comment. phoog's first comment explains why. I am not asking what the raga is *called*. I'm asking whether it *exists*. The former presupposes the latter. The latter is not an identification question.

Comment: And "does this fit the parameters of a raga" is not in fact a useful way to characterize the question when the question itself *provides those very parameters.* The question is whether in fact they have been previously identified as those of a given raga. So I'm at a loss to understand your objections to the question. What am I missing? Are we talking at cross-purposes?

Comment: Maybe you can explain what would constitute an answer to your question. If someone answered the question “yes, it exists”, would you be satisfied with that answer? If not, why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143239/discussion-between-verbose-and-todd-wilcox).